# Converting a Road shp file into a continous Road Raster in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, rasterization, road, resolution

I have converted a Road shp file into a Raster in QGIS, however after the conversion the Road is no longer continous (i.e only the cell corners are touching). I have tried increasing the resolution during conversion however that has not solved the problem. The first image is what I need, the 2nd is my current result.[image: Continous road I would like to achieve]

[image: Discontinous]

[image: method used]

Comment: Please overlay the road shape, as well as add your conversion parameters.

Comment: You could buffer the lines to a desirable thickness and then rasterize that, or apply symbology and export to a tif.

Comment: Buffering the roads has actually offered some success so thanks for that suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Using the gdal tool (Processing Toolbox) called 'rasterize' you can set an advanced parameter to: `-at` (so, minus at)

Your GDAL/OGR console call would look something like this:

```
gdal_rasterize -l layer_name -burn 30.0 -at path_to_data_file temp.tif
```

The documentation for gdal_rasterize is at:
https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_rasterize.html#gdal-rasterize

Hope it works

**Update**

The advanced option is typed in by hand.

[image]

Comment: thank you for the answer. I have opened up the processing toolbox, but I can't seem to find a specific GDAL rasterize option. The vector to Raster option then doesn't offer a advanced setting where you can choose the - at option. I am using QGIS 3.4

Comment: Check in: Processing Toolbox - GDAL - Vector Conversion - Rasterize (vector to raster)

Comment: I have followed that path however I still can't find the option for -at

Comment: can you add a screen-shot of the tool that you are using?

Comment: sorry for slow reply. I have added the tool used to the question.

Comment: strange... the German version does not seem to have that option. It should be between 'Rasterisierung umkehren' and the output name.

Comment: I am using QGIS 3.10

Have you checked any of the other rasterizing tools under GDAL?

You might try - copying the 'GDAL/OGR Console call' (GDAL/OGR Aufruf) to a text editor, add "-at" to the call just before the input file is given and then copy the whole lot to the python console.

Comment: Yeah its strange, I can't find out why there is the difference. Using the Python console is a good suggestion however so I will explore that.